# generic class and generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

```
class test <T> where T : class
{
    public void Write<T>()
    {
        Console.Write(typeof(T).FullName);
    }
}
```

In the above class, it is possible to pass in a string for the class (`test<string> Test = new test<string>`) and then int for the method? If so, what is the output? If not, what problems does this cause? I haven't actually tried this, despite using generics (in my own classes) and generic collections, frequently.

The way I write/see generic classes is as follows:

```
class <T> where T : class
{
    public T Write()
    {
        Console.Write(T.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was originally written no you cannot.  In order to use different types at different points in the class, you must have multiple generic parameters.  It is possible to define a different one at the method level and get your sample to work

```
class Test<T> where T : class {
  public void Write<U>(U arg1) {
    Console.WriteLine(arg1.ToString());
  }
}
```

Usage

```
var t = new Test<string>();
t.Write(42);
```

As Scott pointed out you can use the same named parameter.  Although doing so will cause a warning and generally speaking confuse people.  It is much cleaner to have distinct names for all generic parameters currently in scope.

Comment: If you look at the method, the "T" is actually a method parameter. It has the same name as the class's parameter, and so will generate a warning. However, it's not actually illegal here.

(although I would recommend renaming it to U, like you suggest)

Comment: @Scott, I actually thought C# would issue an error there vs. a warning.  Weird :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting to declare a type variable in the method separately to the class -

```
class Test<T> where T : class {

    public void Method<U>(U val) {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(U).FullName);
    }

}
```

Comment: I wasn't actually trying to do anything. I had to take an exam on C# today and I came up with a question/code very similar to what I suggest. I wasn't sure of the answer so I thought I would ask here. Unfortunately, I can't remember the code exactly as it was.